# Weird Issue reading to a TreeSet

Tags: java, android, cyanogenmod

I seem to be having a weird issue where it is faster to read a file into an `ArrayList` and from that `ArrayList` read it to a `TreeSet` than to add the data directly to the `TreeSet`. I can't seem to understand the problem.

```
public TreeSet<String> readFile(){
    TreeSet<String> dict = null;
    try {
        dict = new TreeSet<String>();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("dictionary")));
        String line;

        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            line = line.split(SEPARATOR)[0];
            dict.add(line);
        }

    }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return dict;
}
```

Also this problem seems to be related with the split function since it works at normal speed without it.
My input file haves around 160 000 lines.
ArrayList with TreeSet takes around 2000 ms.
TreeSet takes around 100 000 ms.

ArrayList -> TreeSet Code

```
public TreeSet<String> readFile(){
    ArrayList<String> dict = null;
    try {
        dict = new ArrayList<String>();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("dictionary")));
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            line = line.split(SEPARATOR)[0];
            dict.add(line);
        }
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    TreeSet<String> tree = new TreeSet<String>();
    for(String word:dict){
        tree.add(word);
    }
    return tree;
}
```

Currently using OnePlus One with Cyanogenmod for the tests.

Comment: can you try using substring instead of split. you are just taking first element of total array that split will generate.

Comment: yes  "line = line.substring(0,line.indexOf(':'));" is also faster, but i'm trying to understand why split would be slower but only with treeSet

Comment: Could you post the code, on how you exactly move data from ArrayList to TreeSet. Also the split(SEPARATOR) is redundant. Use split(SEPARATOR,1) for optimal effect.

Tree set is naturally slower as it performs sorting. But this doesnt explain the ArrayList+TreeSet combination output.

Comment: limit also seems to make it faster and act normal

Comment: @Opetion How do you pass the data from ArrayList to TreeSet?

Comment: foreach and tree.add(), will update moment

Comment: then it should be definitely higher than using only TreeSet. because it s time of inserting into arrayList + time for inserting Treeset. not making any sense. post your this implementation as well so we can have look

Comment: Just added the ArrayList -> TreeSet code

Comment: Why not creating `new TreeSet<String>(dict);` ?

Comment: @VinayVeluri the foreach loop was the first thing that came to my mind, but even if I change that. It won't change the question.

Answer (score 0):

`TreeSet` uses `Comparable` defined over `String` and will try to do sorting `n` times --> size of the Strings that you are going to add.

`ArrayList` just adds as per index and doesnt have any background operation running over.

When once it reaches all `TreeSet` has to sort as per the defined rules.

Defined here : [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)

```
Costs guaranteed log(n) for basic operations
```

Comment: But this doesn't explain why combination of ArrayList + TreeSet works at regular speed, does it?

Comment: ok I understand that but does it make sense that it is faster to put everything on a arraylist and then to put it in the treeset?

Comment: @Jitsu The difference between addition of `String` to TreeSet in loop Vs adding them to ArrayList. Wont that make any difference in execution ? Its not about the combination.

Comment: @Opetion Why not if you need faster execution and not to break the contract of following `Set` principles ?

Comment: @VinayVeluri One of OP questions was why TreeSet attains 100 000ms, while adding to ArrayList and then to TreeSet is faster, which is at first illogical. That is what I'm trying to answer.

Comment: @Jitsu Adding + doing the sort operation for n times is more. ArrayList doesnt do any sorting on adding item. What is not logical in the question ?

Comment: @VinayVeluri Check the new OP code. That is what I was talking about. The thing you spoke of is absolutely clear and concise.

Comment: ok. I think I'm understanding that it is a compiler optimization. that probably recognizes that i'm just adding each word to the TreeSet and so it sorts the arraylist and uses an optimized algorithm for the TreeSet

Comment: but it still doesn't make sense why only with split function without the limit.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are reading a file that is *already sorted*. Immediately inserting then would tend to create a linear list, or require continuously rebalancing the tree to prevent this.

`TreeSet.addAll(Collection)` first sorts (relatively fast for a sorted list), and then uses an optimized algorithm knowing that the elements are sorted to build a (balanced) tree.

Comment: yup the file is already sorted. But does it still make sense since i'm just foreach looping the arraylist and adding each string? is it some optimization from the compiler?

Comment: No, sorry I did not see. Inserts in a TreeSet take longer, and use more more memory maybe combined with reading they cause the reading to stutter either on reading or on total memory consumption.